# Today Widget indented / doesn't use all space

Tags: xcode, autolayout, uistoryboard, today-extension

Building a Today Widget in iOS, and my view doesn't take up the full width of the screen:

[image]

See in the above screenshot that anything that goes beyond that point of the screen gets cut off.

I have set this up using the standard storyboard provided with the Today Widget extension:

[image]

This is confusing to me because I see plenty of other app's Today extensions use the full width of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to implement `widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets:` like this

```
   func widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets(defaultMarginInsets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIEdgeInsets {
      return UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
```

check [Apple Doc - Design the UI](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Today.html)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Shame on me for not reading the docs!